# Retrieve multidimensional database objects directories

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssas, olap

I am trying to list all objects (Cube, dimension, partition, ...) found in a SSAS server. I am able to do that using the following  project:

- [GitHub - SSASAMODB](https://github.com/msornakumar/SSASAMODB)

I am trying to retrieve the relevant directory (within the data directory) for each object. I am unable to do that since files names contains some Incremental number that change each time you made changes to the objects in the database. Example:

- Cube name: TestCube

*Folder:*

```
|Data Dir|\<SSASDB>\TestCube.0.cub
```

After changing and reprocessing the Cube it changes to another value

```
|Data Dir|\<SSASDB>\TestCube.1.cub
```

Is there is a property in AMO classes that returns the Folder Path of each object? What is the value of the Incremental number included in the Folder name? Is there some workaround to do that?

---

*Since i only have SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence tools installed i need a solution compatible with **SSIS script Task** since it is the only way that i can process the data. Note that there are [many articles online for using AMO from script task](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2796/create-sql-server-analysis-services-partitions-using-amo/)*

***Environment:*** SQL Server 2014

Comment: Does @Hadi's excellent answer solve the issue or is that final sentence about needing this to work from the confines of an SSIS Script Task the reason for the bounty?

Comment: @billinkc yes the issue was solved and the classes provided can be used within a script task. I didn't award the bounty to give the answer more up-votes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Since you mentioned a cube as example, it means that you are working with multidimensional model not tabular.*

## SSAS Data directory contents hierarchy

After building many multidimensional Cube using SSAS, i can assume that the following tree is the Data directory hierarchy:

```
|- Data Directory
    |- Database (.db)
        |- Dimension (.dim)
        |- Role (.role)
        |- Mining Structure (.dms)
        |- Data Source (.ds)
        |- Data Source View (.dsv)
        |- Multidimensional Cube (.cub)
            |- Measure Group (.det)
                |- Partition (.prt)
                |- AggregationDesign (.agg)
```

Each object from the tree above can be stored in form of a directory or/and an XML file.

The Actions and Kpis information are stored within the Cube XML configuration file.

*Example:*

- Object: Cube
- Directory: `<DataDir>\<database>\<cube ID>.cub\`
- XML file: `<DataDir>\<database>\<cube ID>.cub.xml`

## Link SSAS AMO objects to data directory files

### Reading data using AMO

To read SSAS object from deployed Analysis Cube, i improved the code of the following project to add more objects and to link them with the relevant directories/files.

- [SSASAMODB](https://github.com/msornakumar/SSASAMODB)

### Updated method

To map every AMO object to the relevant directory/XML file we have to loop over objects starting from top level (database) and retrieve the files/directories found in each level and map it using the .ID property and the extensions (as mentioned in the tree above)

The following code is written in C# and it is an updated version of the method published in the link above:

**Note that the method only works on local servers or you must have a Mapped network drive with the same letter of the Original drive that contains the data directory. In addition you must have the permission to access the Analysis Server objects**

*The code is considered as a proof of concept, and can be improved*

#### SSASObject Class

```
public class SSASObject
{

    public enum ObjectType{

        Cube = 0,
        MeasureGroup = 1,
        Dimension = 2,
        Partition = 3,
        AggregationDesign = 4,
        MiningStructure = 5,
        Role = 6,
        DataSource = 7,
        DataSourceView = 8,
        Database = 9,
        Server = 10,
        Kpi = 11,
        Action = 12

    }

    public int ID { get; set; } //incremental ID 
    public int? ParentID { get; set; } // Parent incremental ID
    public ObjectType Type { get; set; } // The Object type
    public string ObjectID { get; set; } // Object ID defined in SSAS
    public string ObjectName { get; set; } // Object Name defined in SSAS
    public string Extension { get; set; } // The Object extension
    public string FolderPath { get; set; } // The Object related directory
    public string FolderName { get; set; } // The directory name
    public DateTime? FolderModifiedDate { get; set; } // The directory last modified date
    public string FolderIncremetalID { get; set; } // The Incremental Number mentioned in the directory name
    public string XMLFilePath { get; set; } // The Object related XML file
    public string XMLFileName { get; set; } // The XML file name
    public DateTime? XmlModifiedDate { get; set; } // The XML file last modified date
    public string XmlIncremetalID { get; set; }  // The incremental number mentioned in the XML file name      


}
```

#### SSASAMO Class

```
public static class SSASAMO
{
    public static List<SSASObject> ReadMeta(string ServerName)
    {
        try
        {


            List<SSASObject> result = new List<SSASObject>();

            String ConnStr;

            DateTime? dt = null;
            int idx = 0;
            int DbID = 0;
            int CubeID = 0;
            int ObjectID = 0;

            string DataDir;
            string OLAPServerName = ServerName;

            ConnStr = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + OLAPServerName + ";";

            Server OLAPServer = new Server();
            OLAPServer.Connect(ConnStr);

            DataDir = OLAPServer.ServerProperties["DataDir"].Value;

            string[] DatabasesDir = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DataDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            string[] DatabasesFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DataDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            result.Add(new SSASObject
            {
                ID = idx,
                ParentID = null,
                FolderModifiedDate = System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(DataDir),
                FolderPath = DataDir,
                ObjectName = OLAPServerName,
                Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.Server
            });

            // Database
            foreach (Database OLAPDatabase in OLAPServer.Databases)
            {


                string CurrentDbDir = DatabasesDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(DataDir + "\\" +  OLAPDatabase.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".db")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                string CurrentDbXmlFile = DatabasesFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(DataDir + "\\" + OLAPDatabase.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".db.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                string[] DbObjectsDir = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(CurrentDbDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                string[] DbObjectsFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CurrentDbDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);


                idx++;
                DbID = idx;
                result.Add(new SSASObject
                {
                    ID = idx,
                    ParentID = 0,
                    ObjectID = OLAPDatabase.ID,
                    FolderModifiedDate = CurrentDbDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentDbDir),
                    XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDbXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDbXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                    Extension = ".db",
                    FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CurrentDbDir),
                    FolderPath = CurrentDbDir,
                    ObjectName = OLAPDatabase.Name,
                    Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.Database,
                    XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CurrentDbXmlFile),
                    XMLFilePath = CurrentDbXmlFile,
                    XmlModifiedDate = CurrentDbXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentDbXmlFile),
                    FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDbDir).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDbDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)
                });



                //Data Source
                foreach (DataSource OLAPDataSource in OLAPDatabase.DataSources)
                {
                    idx++;
                    string CurrentDataSourceDir = DbObjectsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPDataSource.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".ds")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    string CurrentDataSourceXmlFile = DbObjectsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPDataSource.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".ds.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    result.Add(new SSASObject
                    {
                        ID = idx,
                        ParentID = DbID,
                        ObjectID = OLAPDataSource.ID,
                        FolderModifiedDate = CurrentDataSourceDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentDataSourceDir),
                        XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                      System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                      System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                        Extension = ".ds",
                        FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CurrentDataSourceDir),
                        FolderPath = CurrentDbDir,
                        ObjectName = OLAPDataSource.Name,
                        Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.DataSource,
                        XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CurrentDataSourceXmlFile),
                        XMLFilePath = CurrentDataSourceXmlFile,
                        XmlModifiedDate = CurrentDataSourceXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentDataSourceXmlFile),
                        FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceDir).Substring(
                                                      System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)
                    });


                }

                //Data Source View
                foreach (DataSourceView OLAPDataSourceView in OLAPDatabase.DataSourceViews)
                {
                    idx++;
                    string CurrentDataSourceViewDir = DbObjectsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPDataSourceView.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dsv")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    string CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile = DbObjectsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPDataSourceView.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dsv.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    result.Add(new SSASObject
                    {
                        ID = idx,
                        ParentID = DbID,
                        ObjectID = OLAPDataSourceView.ID,
                        FolderModifiedDate = CurrentDataSourceViewDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentDataSourceViewDir),
                        XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                      System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                      System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                        Extension = ".dsv",
                        FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CurrentDataSourceViewDir),
                        FolderPath = CurrentDbDir,
                        ObjectName = OLAPDataSourceView.Name,
                        Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.DataSourceView,
                        XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile),
                        XMLFilePath = CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile,
                        XmlModifiedDate = CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentDataSourceViewXmlFile),
                        FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceViewDir).Substring(
                                                      System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentDataSourceViewDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)
                    });


                }


                //Dimension
                foreach (Dimension OLAPDimension in OLAPDatabase.Dimensions)
                {

                    idx++;
                    string DimensionDir = DbObjectsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPDimension.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dim")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    string DimensionXmlFile = DbObjectsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPDimension.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dim.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                    result.Add(new SSASObject
                    {
                        ID = idx,
                        ParentID = DbID,
                        ObjectID = OLAPDimension.ID,
                        FolderModifiedDate = DimensionDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(DimensionDir),
                        XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DimensionXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DimensionXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                        Extension = ".dim",
                        FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DimensionDir),
                        FolderPath = DimensionDir,
                        ObjectName = OLAPDimension.Name,
                        Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.Dimension,
                        XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DimensionXmlFile),
                        XMLFilePath = DimensionXmlFile,
                        XmlModifiedDate = DimensionXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(DimensionXmlFile),
                        FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DimensionDir).Substring(
                                             System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DimensionDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)
                    });
                }

                // Cube
                foreach (Cube OLAPCubex in OLAPDatabase.Cubes)
                {


                    idx++;
                    CubeID = idx;

                    string CubeDir = DbObjectsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPCubex.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".cub")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    string CubeXmlFile = DbObjectsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPCubex.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".cub.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                    string[] CubeMeasureGroupsDir = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(CubeDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                    string[] CubeMeasureGroupsFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CubeDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);


                    result.Add(new SSASObject
                    {
                        ID = idx,
                        ParentID = DbID,
                        ObjectID = OLAPCubex.ID,
                        FolderModifiedDate = CubeDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CubeDir),
                        XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CubeXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CubeXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                        Extension = ".cub",
                        FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CubeDir),
                        FolderPath = CubeDir,
                        ObjectName = OLAPCubex.Name,
                        Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.Cube,
                        XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CubeXmlFile),
                        XMLFilePath = CubeXmlFile,
                        XmlModifiedDate = CubeXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(CubeXmlFile),
                        FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CubeDir).Substring(
                                             System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CubeDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)
                    });

                    //Measure Group
                    foreach (MeasureGroup OLAPMeasureGroup in OLAPCubex.MeasureGroups)
                    {

                        idx++;
                        ObjectID = idx;
                        string MeasureGroupDir = CubeMeasureGroupsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CubeDir + "\\" + OLAPMeasureGroup.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".det")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                        string MeasureGroupXmlFile = CubeMeasureGroupsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CubeDir + "\\" + OLAPMeasureGroup.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".det.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                        string[] GroupPartitionDir = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(MeasureGroupDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                        string[] GroupPartitionFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(MeasureGroupDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                        result.Add(new SSASObject
                        {
                            ID = idx,
                            ParentID = CubeID,
                            ObjectID = OLAPMeasureGroup.ID,
                            FolderModifiedDate = MeasureGroupDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(MeasureGroupDir),
                            XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MeasureGroupXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MeasureGroupXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                            Extension = ".det",
                            FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MeasureGroupDir),
                            FolderPath = MeasureGroupDir,
                            ObjectName = OLAPMeasureGroup.Name,
                            Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.MeasureGroup,
                            XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MeasureGroupXmlFile),
                            XMLFilePath = MeasureGroupXmlFile,
                            XmlModifiedDate = MeasureGroupXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(MeasureGroupXmlFile),
                            FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MeasureGroupDir).Substring(
                                                 System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MeasureGroupDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)
                        });

                        //Aggregations
                        foreach (AggregationDesign OLAPAggregationDesign in OLAPMeasureGroup.AggregationDesigns)
                        {

                            string AggregationDir = GroupPartitionDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(MeasureGroupDir + "\\" + OLAPAggregationDesign.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".agg")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                            string AggregationXmlFile = GroupPartitionFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(MeasureGroupDir + "\\" + OLAPAggregationDesign.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".agg.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                            idx++;

                            result.Add(new SSASObject
                            {
                                ID = idx,
                                ParentID = ObjectID,
                                ObjectID = OLAPAggregationDesign.ID,
                                FolderModifiedDate = AggregationDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(AggregationDir),
                                XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AggregationXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AggregationXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                                Extension = ".agg",
                                FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AggregationDir),
                                FolderPath = AggregationDir,
                                ObjectName = OLAPAggregationDesign.Name,
                                Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.AggregationDesign,
                                XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AggregationXmlFile),
                                XMLFilePath = AggregationXmlFile,
                                XmlModifiedDate = AggregationXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(AggregationXmlFile),
                                FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AggregationDir).Substring(
                                                     System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AggregationDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)

                            });


                        }


                        //Partitions
                        foreach (Partition OLAPPartition in OLAPMeasureGroup.Partitions)
                        {

                            string PartitionDir = GroupPartitionDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(MeasureGroupDir + "\\" + OLAPPartition.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".prt")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                            string PartitionXmlFile = GroupPartitionFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(MeasureGroupDir + "\\" + OLAPPartition.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".prt.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                            idx++;

                            result.Add(new SSASObject
                            {
                                ID = idx,
                                ParentID = ObjectID,
                                ObjectID = OLAPPartition.ID,
                                FolderModifiedDate = PartitionDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(PartitionDir),
                                XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PartitionXmlFile)).Substring(
                                                  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PartitionXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                                Extension = ".prt",
                                FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PartitionDir),
                                FolderPath = PartitionDir,
                                ObjectName = OLAPPartition.Name,
                                Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.Partition,
                                XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PartitionXmlFile),
                                XMLFilePath = PartitionXmlFile,
                                XmlModifiedDate = PartitionXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(PartitionXmlFile),
                                FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PartitionDir).Substring(
                                                     System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PartitionDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)

                            });

                        }






                    }


                }

                //Mining Structure
                foreach (MiningStructure OLAPMiningStructure in OLAPDatabase.MiningStructures)
                {

                    idx++;

                    string MiningStructureDir = DbObjectsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPMiningStructure.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dms")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    string MiningStructureXmlFile = DbObjectsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPMiningStructure.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dms.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                    result.Add(new SSASObject
                    {
                        ID = idx,
                        ParentID = DbID,
                        ObjectID = OLAPMiningStructure.ID,
                        FolderModifiedDate = MiningStructureDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(MiningStructureDir),
                        XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                          System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MiningStructureXmlFile)).Substring(
                                          System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MiningStructureXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                        Extension = ".ds",
                        FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MiningStructureDir),
                        FolderPath = MiningStructureDir,
                        ObjectName = OLAPMiningStructure.Name,
                        Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.MiningStructure,
                        XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MiningStructureXmlFile),
                        XMLFilePath = MiningStructureXmlFile,
                        XmlModifiedDate = MiningStructureXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(MiningStructureXmlFile),
                        FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MiningStructureDir).Substring(
                                             System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MiningStructureDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)

                    });
                }


                //Role
                foreach (Role OLAPRole in OLAPDatabase.Roles)
                {

                    idx++;

                    string RoleDir = DbObjectsDir.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPRole.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dms")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
                    string RoleXmlFile = DbObjectsFiles.Where(x => x.StartsWith(CurrentDbDir + "\\" + OLAPRole.ID.ToString() + ".") && x.EndsWith(".dms.xml")).DefaultIfEmpty("").First();

                    result.Add(new SSASObject
                    {
                        ID = idx,
                        ParentID = DbID,
                        ObjectID = OLAPRole.ID,
                        FolderModifiedDate = RoleDir == "" ? dt : System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime(RoleDir),
                        XmlIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                                          System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RoleXmlFile)).Substring(
                                          System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RoleXmlFile).IndexOf(".") + 1),
                        Extension = ".ds",
                        FolderName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(RoleDir),
                        FolderPath = RoleDir,
                        ObjectName = OLAPRole.Name,
                        Type = SSASObject.ObjectType.Role,
                        XMLFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(RoleXmlFile),
                        XMLFilePath = RoleXmlFile,
                        XmlModifiedDate = RoleXmlFile == "" ? dt : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(RoleXmlFile),
                        FolderIncremetalID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RoleDir).Substring(
                                             System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RoleDir).IndexOf(".") + 1)

                    });

                }

            }



            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

### GitHub project

I create a small windows application and upload it to GitHub, you can use it as a separate tool, or you can simply copy to Classes in the Script Task project and use it within the Script.

- [GitHub - MetaCube](https://github.com/HadiFadl/MetaCube)
- [GitHub - MetaCube Classes](https://github.com/HadiFadl/MetaCube/tree/master/MetaCube/Classes)

Comment: Please we need the github link

Comment: @amd i added the link, check it out